# How to clarify whether an adverb at the end of serial list modifies each item vs just the last item?

Tags: adverbs, list-order

In the recreational community where my family has property, the common understanding has always been that no rentals are allowed, period.  Not everyone agrees.  This is the policy as it was written in 1989: "No cabins, trailers, lots or any part or parcel of ABC Park may be rented, leased, lease-option or loaned long-term."

One person thinks that the "long-term" modifies to each part of the list, while our understanding was that it only modifies the "lease-option or loaned."

What do you think?

Comment: Vague language will always be interpreted to one's own advantage. It means what you say, but can be distorted to mean the other: short-term renting and short-term leasing are fine. Either way, better define long-term.

Comment: Comma use and interpretation has a long history in law, where exactly this argument is litigated. The typical interpretations have "long-term" modifying everything back to rented, and the other interpretation has "long-term" only modifying "loaned". The Oxford comma here after lease-option wouldn't help. You may find  more satisfactory answer on law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It probably modifies only “loaned,” because it is unlikely that the policy intended to forbid owners from letting friends and other family stay there for short periods of time. In a lrgal case it’s likely that one could demonstrate that friends and relatives were there when the legal owners were not present.

Comment: It needs to be reworded.